# How correctly open window to form and add value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
(function aaa(){
    var a = window.open("https://site.ru/q/1919", "hello", "width=1500,height=1000");
    jQuery(".form--text").val("hello");
}())
```

This line is not working. Why? How can I correct it?

```
jQuery(".form--text").val("hello");
```

Comment: jquery deals with the LOCAL document (the one calling your window.open call). you have to explicitly target the document in the window you opened up.

Comment: The DOM of the new window is separate to the opener. You could do what you need by sending the value in the URL and reading it on the receiving page